# how to properly nest mappings in an index in kibana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I am trying create an index ,which has nested mapping, but I'm not sure what the json data should look like. I am using kibana version v 7.4.2. the sample below works, but If when i try to add any nested mappings ( sample 2) , i get error at the end.

sample 1

```
PUT testIndex?pretty=true 
{
   "mappings":{
      "_doc":{
         "properties":{
            "time":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"HH:mm:ss"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

sample 2

```
PUT testIndex?pretty=true 
{
   "mappings":{
      "_doc":{
         "properties":{
            "time":{
               "type":"date",
               "format":"HH:mm:ss"
            }
         },
         "predicted":{
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{
               "numofreq":{
                          "type":"integer"
                         }
                 }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true."
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifiying _doc type is depricated in newer version of elasticsearch

 this should work

sample 1

```
PUT testindex?pretty=true 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sample 2

```
PUT testindex1?pretty=true 
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "predicted": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "numofreq": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```